# Need help concerning functions within my existing code

Tags: python, function

I am needing some help/guidance as to how to apply functions to my already existing code. I have the While and for loop going correctly and the code runs, but I have to make it to where I add functions and call them under my if statements.

Here is what I have to accomplish---  A function to greet the user to this program and provide menu choices. This function will not take any arguments.  b. Functions to convert from Imperial/US units to metric units.  i. Each function will take an imperial/US unit as the argument ii. It will convert to the corresponding metric unit. You will need to find the conversion formula(s) online for each of the below conversions. iii. Make sure you have a return statement in your function definition. iv. When you call the function, assign the function to a variable and print the variable to the user.  v. Imperial/US units to be converted. 1. Miles to Kilometers 2. Yards to Meters 3. Inches to centimeters 4. Fahrenheit to Celsius 5. Pounds to Kilogram  c. Create a while loop to ask for user input (on which conversion they want) and call the functions in the metric conversion module.

Here is my code so far---

```
print(".....................Metric Conversion........................")

def welcome():
    print("Hello, the purpose of this program is to give the conversion for Imperial/US units.")

def miles(miles):
    return 

def Yards(yards):
    return yards

def Inches(inches):
    return inches

def kilogram(kilogram):
    return kilogram

calculate = 'yes'
while calculate:
    print('''    1) Mile to Kilometers
    2) Yards to Meters
    3) Inches to Centimeters
    4) Fahrenheit to Celsius
    5)Pounds to Kilgrams''')
    answer = input("Please choose and option ")

    if answer == '1':
        miles = float(input("Please enter the Mile to convert to kilometer  "))
        conversion_factor = 1.609
        kilometers = miles * conversion_factor
        print("The conversion from Miles to Kilometers is: ",kilometers)

    elif answer =='2':
        yards = float(input("Please enter the Yard to convert to Meters:  "))
        conversion_rate = 0.9144
        meters = yards * conversion_rate
        print("The conversion from Yards to Meters is: ",meters)

    elif answer =='3':
        inches = float(input("Please enter the Inch to convert to centimeters: "))
        conversion_rate = 2.54
        centimeters = inches * conversion_rate
        print("The conversion from Inches to Centimeters is: ", centimeters)

    elif answer =='4':
        fahrenheit = float(input("Please enter the degree in Fahrenheit to find the Celsius:  "))
        celsius = (fahrenheit -32) *5.0/9.0
        print("The conversion from Fahrenheit to Celsius is: ", celsius)

    elif answer == '5':
        pounds = float(input("Please enter the Pound to convert to Kilogram: "))
        conversion_rate = 0.453592
        kilograms = pounds * conversion_rate
        print("The conversion from Pounds to Kilograms is: ", kilograms)


    else:
        print("You must enter in one of the available options.")

    calculate = input("Would you like to calulate again? ")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is less redundancy, you could also imagine using a class like this:

```
class Converter:
    def __init__(self, imperial_unit_name, metric_unit_name, factor):
        self.imperial_unit_name = imperial_unit_name
        self.metric_unit_name = metric_unit_name
        self.factor = factor # you could also add an offset if needed

    def run(self):
        miles = float(input("Please enter the {} to convert to {}: "
                            .format(self.imperial_unit_name,self.metric_unit_name)))
        print("The conversion from {} to {} is: {}"
              .format(self.imperial_unit_name,self.metric_unit_name, miles * self.factor))

# Use as many conversions as you want
conversions = [ ("Miles", "Kilometers", 1.609), ("Inches","Centimeters",2.54) ]
```

And then, to do a conversion:

```
answer = 1
Converter(*conversions[answer]).run()
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not looking for less redundancy. More or less the syntax of how to use def within my code to grab the variable when asked for input from the user. Thank you for the response!